# Opening new form in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7

Tags: winforms, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How do I show a new form in a Windows Phone 7 App?
I've initialized my class like this:

```
Jeans jeansform = new Jeans("Elwood Curtis");
```

However, there's no jeansform.Show() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally windows phone 7 application use a form navigation similar to a silverlight navigation application hosted by a browser.  This allows the phone back button to navigate back from "pages" which have been navigated to.

Your `Jeans` "form" should actually derive from `PhoneApplicationPage` and should have a simple default constructor (not one that accepts a parameter as you have at present).

You would then navigate to your page with code like this:-

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Jeans.xml?name=Elwood%20Curtis"));
```

Your "Jeans" page then does most of its initial configuration in `OnNavigatedTo`:-

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(Microsoft.Phone.Navigation.PhoneNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        Name = NavigationContext.QueryString["name"];
        // Other code you would have otherwise run in a parameterised constructor
    }
```